# how to Preview the video file that user wants to upload on the website (PHP, FiileAPI JS)

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, web, html5-video, fileapi

I mean, when a user chooses the video file from their system, have the web-page already show them the files they want to upload.

I'm already using image file to preview using FileAPI JS. The same I want to do with FileAPI JS for video file.

(So, It must be work within my client side)

Thanks & answers are appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use [FileReader](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader) or [createObjectURL](http://caniuse.com/#feat=bloburls). They'll both get the job done, but FileReader has slightly broader support in browsers.

`createObjectURL` will run synchronously and return a Blob URL, a short string referencing the file in memory. and you can free it up immediately after you're done using it.

`FileReader` will run asynchronously, requiring a callback, providing a Data URI, a much longer string representing the whole file. This can be very big and will be freed from memory in Javascript garbage collection.

Here's an example that first tries `createObjectURL` and falls back to `FileReader`. (Please provide your own error checking, etc.)

```
var video = document.getElementById('video'),
    input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('change', function (evt) {
    var reader = new window.FileReader(),
        file = evt.target.files[0],
        url;

        reader = window.URL || window.webKitURL;

    if (reader && reader.createObjectURL) {
        url = reader.createObjectURL(file);
        video.src = url;
        reader.revokeObjectURL(url);  //free up memory
        return;
    }

    if (!window.FileReader) {
        console.log('Sorry, not so much');
        return;
    }

    reader = new window.FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(evt) {
       video.src = evt.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}, false);
```

Working example here: http://jsbin.com/isodes/1/edit

Mozilla has a [more detailed article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/) with instructions on how to upload once you've got your file.

IE10 supports both, but IE9 supports neither, so you'll have to fall back to a regular form upload without a preview.

Comment: Any sense if the FileReader method works on iOS?  I have it running in Safari for OSX, but when I try the same code on iOS 6 the video just sits there as a black box.