# How to preview a video before and after upload using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, filereader

I want to show a preview of uploaded video file before submit. I have successfully done this with an image thanks to the following JS, but it is not working with video files...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {

    $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
      var files = e.target.files,
        filesLength = files.length;

      for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
        var f = files[i]
        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = (function(e) {

          var file = e.target;
          $("<img></img>", {
            class: "imageThumb",
            src: e.target.result,
            title: file.name
          }).insertAfter("#files");

        });

        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
    });

  } else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
  }
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14517519/1018966

Comment: Be ware of `FileReader` browser support. Here you can find another example/experiment: https://gist.github.com/ispedals/5613344

Answer (score 0):

Video files are typically larger and harder for the FileReader class to comprehend.

Try using the window.URL.createObjectURL function for this (make sure this is properly accessed on supported browsers as some require vendor prefixes).

You should best check the following resources:

1. http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/06/Don-t-Build-Blobs-Construct-Them
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL
3. [URL.createObjectURL for audio blob gives TypeError in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481216/url-createobjecturl-for-audio-blob-gives-typeerror-in-firefox)

I guess it's needless to say the browser should support the video format.